# String split hide and removes "\" character

Tags: string, actionscript-3, split

I got a strange problem with split function over the String. Please look at my example, How can I figure it out? Does It remove “\” from String by default?

```
public function code01():void {
    qrShow("C:/Documents and Settings/me/Desktop/a.gif;C:/Documents and Settings/me/Desktop/b.gif");
    qrShow("C:\Documents and Settings\me\Desktop\a.gif;C:\Documents and Settings\me\Desktop\b.gif");
}

public function qrShow(u:String):void{
    var imgArray:Array = u.split(";");
    for each(var addrs:String in imgArray) {
        trace (" --- " + addrs);
    }
}
```

The result is as follows:

> --- C:/Documents and Settings/me/Desktop/a.gif
>
> --- C:/Documents and Settings/me/Desktop/b.gif
>
> --- C:Documents and SettingsmeDesktopa.gif  <--- why no "\" ?
>
> --- C:Documents and SettingsmeDesktop.gif  <--- why no "\" and also "b" is changed !!!?

Is this a bug in Flash?

Comment: Escape character ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape a backslash (with another backslash).

For example try run this:

```
trace("\");
```

You'll get an error.

You need to do this:

```
trace("\\"); // Output: \
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it's actually because a backslash `\` is the escape character in ActionScript. It's usually used to change the meaning of anything following it, though if the following character doesn't have a special meaning, the backslash is simply ignored. So to fix your code, double the backslashes:

```
qrShow("C:\\Documents and Settings\\me\\Desktop\\a.gif;C:\\Documents and Settings\\me\\Desktop\\b.gif");
```